# True/false statements within if statements and for loops

Tags: python, list, boolean, append, nameerror

I have multiple lists within a list, and want to check multiple things and form a new list with `if` conditions and `True` or `False`. My code:

```
import re
runlist = [['229', '134', '9'], ['229', '137', '5'], ['629', '140', '5'], ['631', '140', '5'], ['632', '140', '5'], ['633', '140', '8'], ['422', '141', '5'], ['628', '141', '9'], ['629', '141', '11']], [['629', '145', '8'], ['630', '145', '8'], ['631', '145', '8'], ['632', '145', '8'], ['632', '146', '5']], ...]
goodrunslist = []
for i in range(len(runlist)):
    for k in range (0, len(runlist[i])):
        if re.match('[2][0-5][0-9]', runlist[i][k][0]):
            ch2 = True
    for m in range (0, len(runlist[i])):
        if re.match('[6][0-4][0-9]', runlist[i][m][0]):
            ch4 = True
    if ch2 and ch4:
        goodrunslist.append(runlist[i])
```

However, under the first `for` loop at the end, it gives me a `NameError` that `ch2` and `ch4` are not defined, so it can't append anything to the new list. How can I fix this?

Edit: I've fixed the `NameError` by the below code, but now my problem is that the new list isn't returning anything (it's returning `[]`), even though I can see that it should have some elements in it. The new code is below. Any fixes or suggestions are appreciated; thanks!

```
import re
runlist = [['229', '134', '9'], ['229', '137', '5'], ['629', '140', '5'], ['631', '140', '5'], ['632', '140', '5'], ['633', '140', '8'], ['422', '141', '5'], ['628', '141', '9'], ['629', '141', '11']], [['629', '145', '8'], ['630', '145', '8'], ['631', '145', '8'], ['632', '145', '8'], ['632', '146', '5']], ...]
goodrunslist = []
ch2, ch4 = False, False
for i in range(len(runlist)):
    for k in range (0, len(runlist[i])):
        if re.match('[2][0-5][0-9]', runlist[i][k][0]):
            ch2 = True
        else:
            ch2 = False
    for m in range (0, len(runlist[i])):
        if re.match('[6][0-4][0-9]', runlist[i][m][0]):
            ch4 = True
        else:
            ch4 = False
    if ch2 and ch4:
        goodrunslist.append(runlist[i])
```

Comment: You would need to initialize those variables to `False` above the inner loop, so that they have a defined value whether or not any matches were found.

Comment: `ch2 and ch4` will never be true. Your numbers cannot start with both a 2 **and** 6

Comment: The brackets here are mismatched so this code won't run at all (I simply removed the `,...`. But I got it to successfully add `[['629', '245', '8'], ['245', '245', '8']]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line:

`if ch2 and ch4:`

You reference `ch2` and `ch4` in the scope of the first for loop but they are defined in the scopes of the inner for loops. To get around this declare them first in the scope of the first for loop by adding this line:

`ch2, ch4 = False, False`

below the start of your first for loop.

Update: I would recommend doing this more functionally. This avoids creating local variables using mutations. It also avoids nested loops and ifs. Here is an alternative way to write your code:

```
# This function checks each list within the list to see if it should belong in goodrunslist
def checkRunListItem(runListItem):
      # this generator takes each item in the list and turns it into the boolean that your if statement
      # would use to decide to return true or false

      # any checks if any item in a list is true
      ch2 = any(re.match('[2][0-5][0-9]', item[0]) for item in runListItem)
      ch4 = any(re.match('[6][0-4][0-9]', item[0]) for item in runListItem)
      return ch2 and ch4
goodrunslist = filter(checkRunListItem, runlist)
```

However your conditions seem very strange and I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. The list you provide in your example has mismatched brackets. This code would only add an item to `goodrunslist` if that item were a list of lists of lists where the first elements of the lists within the base list had at least one match for each of your regular expressions. Can you be more specific about the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks, I defined each of them as `False` above the first loop. But I've added another condition in the loop:  `for l in range (0, len(runlist[i])):
        if re.match('^[4][0-5][0-9]$', runlist[i][l][0]):
            ch3 = True
    print ch3`, and now it's telling me that `ch3` is `True` for all of them even though I can clearly see that's not right. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Once you set it to `True` once it stays true. I would recommend doing this in a more functional/pythonic way to avoid confusion like this.

Comment: In response to your edit, what you described is actually exactly what I'm trying to achieve. How can I use your above code to then add each corresponding list of lists of lists to the new `goodrunslist` list?

Comment: Sorry I left `return` there instead of assigning it to the list. `filter` takes a list and creates a new list with items that satisfy conditions. It is a good choice for your use case.

Comment: `any(re.match('[2][0-5][0-9]', item[0]) for item in runListItem)` would look cleaner

Comment: Note that `any()` will return on the first True match, not scan over all the elements like the question was trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loops are over the exact same range, and you are indexing the list the same, so they can be combined.

Also, you don't need a `range()`, as you can iterate over the objects directly.

More importantly, you are checking the first elements of the list (which are all three digits) to see if they match **both** regexes, which won't be ever be true (number can't start with both a `2` and a `6`). I think you meant to use `or`.

```
import re
runlist = [[['229', '134', '9'], ['229', '137', '5'], ['629', '140', '5'], ['631', '140', '5'], ['632', '140', '5'], ['633', '140', '8'], ['422', '141', '5'], ['628', '141', '9'], ['629', '141', '11']], [['629', '145', '8'], ['630', '145', '8'], ['631', '145', '8'], ['632', '145', '8'], ['632', '146', '5']]]
goodrunslist = []
for run in runlist:
    ch2, ch4 = False, False
    for r in run:
        ch2 = re.match('2[0-5][0-9]', r[0])
        ch4 = re.match('6[0-4][0-9]', r[0])
    if ch2 or ch4:
        goodrunslist.append(run)
print(goodrunslist)
```

However, I think the indentation is off here. You are only appending **after** you've scanned over all `i in len(runlist[i])` or `val in run`. So, the condition is only being applied to the last element of `runlist`

The solution would be to intent the check and add the inner list, not the full runlist

```
goodrunslist = []
for run in runlist:
    for r in run:
        ch2 = bool(re.match('2[0-5][0-9]', r[0]))
        ch4 = bool(re.match('6[0-4][0-9]', r[0]))
        if ch2 or ch4:
          goodrunslist.append(r)
print(goodrunslist)
```